# How do you access a method from another class from a different class in Python to edit a Kivy object?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a Pong game using Python and Kivy, but I cannot change the position of the ball. Whenever I try to, the ball doesn't change unless I call the method within the class which I don't want to do.

Python:

```
    #Imported everything

    class PongGame(Widget):
        ball = ObjectProperty()

        def update(self):
            self.ball.pos = (1200, 1200)


    class PongBall(Widget):
        pass

    class PongApp(App):
        def build(self):
            PongGame().update() #Doesn't work (doesn't do anything)
            print(PongGame().ball.pos)) #Not even printing right coordinates
            return PongGame()

     if __name__ = "__main__":
         PongApp().run()
```

Kv:

```
<PongGame>:
    ball: pball

    PongBall:
        id: pball
        pos: (root.center_x - (root.width * 0.05), root.center_y * (1/12))
        size: (root.height * (1/20), root.height * (1/20))

<PongBall>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [1, 1, 1]
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Comment: try removing the self from def update(self)?

Comment: Then how would I access the ball ObjectProperty?

Comment: I think it is a problem with running PongGame().update()

Comment: Have you seen this https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Two open brackets, three closing:

```
print(PongGame().ball.pos))
```

**2)** `=` should be changed to `==`:

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
```

**3)** Here you create 3 different `PongGame` objects (witch would have different states) instead of creating one:

```
PongGame().update() #Doesn't work (doesn't do anything)
print(PongGame().ball.pos)) #Not even printing right coordinates
return PongGame()
```

Should be:

```
root = PongGame()  # Create one object and change it's state.
root.update()
print(root.ball.pos)  # will print 1200, 1200
return root
```

**4)** kvlang binds widgets property to variables it dependence of. So if you want to change ball position in future, you shouldn't bind it to `root` ignoring ball's `pos`. In other words,

```
pos: (root.center_x - (root.width * 0.05), root.center_y * (1/12))
```

should dependence of `self.pos`:

```
pos: self.pos
```

**-)** That's what important.

I also added `on_touch_down` handling to show ball's position changing (just click window to move ball):

```
Builder.load_string(b'''
<PongGame>:
    ball: pball

    PongBall:
        id: pball
        pos: self.pos
        size: 20, 20

<PongBall>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [1, 1, 1]
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty()

    def update(self):
        self.ball.pos = (200, 200)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.ball.pos = touch.pos  # change ball position to point of click


class PongBall(Widget):
    pass


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = PongGame()
        root.update()  # init ball position
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```